# Python Multiple Turtle Screens

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

I wrote a sorting algorithm visualizer and now I want to create a window class so that I can use two separate windows and run one sort per window. However, the origin of the window is off and also the scaling. I want the bottom left to be `(0,0)` and the top left to be `(width, height)`, but for some reason when I goto `(0,0)` the turtle goes the the middle-left of the screen and when I goto `(width, height)` the turtle moves to the top-right of the screen. I can draw as usual, but the scaling seems wrong and also the canvas seems to be anchored by the top, but this is just my speculation. What is happening here and how can I solve it?

```
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, LEFT, BOTH, ALL
class TurtleWindow(Tk):
    # geometry = "800x600+0+0" or "800x600+810+0" 
    def __init__(self,title,geometry:str):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = True
        self.geometry(geometry)
        self.title(title)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy_window)

        self.canvas = Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        self.screen = TurtleScreen(self.canvas)

        tmp = geometry.find("+")
        tmp = geometry[:tmp].split("x")
        self.screen.setworldcoordinates(0,0,int(tmp[0]),int(tmp[1]))

        self.turtle = RawTurtle(self.screen)
        self.turtle.ht()
        self.text_turtle = RawTurtle(self.screen)
        self.text_turtle.ht()
        self.turtle_list = [self.turtle, self.text_turtle]
    
        def new_turtle(self):
            self.turtle_list.append(RawTurtle(self.screen))
            return self.turtle_list[-1]
    
        def update_window(self):
            if self.running:
                self.update()
    
        def destroy_window(self):
            self.running = False
            self.destroy()
    
W,H = 800,600
if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = TurtleWindow("Test", f"{W}x{H}+0+0")
    window.turtle.st()
    window.turtle.goto(0,0)
    window.turtle.goto(W,H)
    input()
```

Comment: Use the ```turtle.ScrolledCanvas``` instead of the ```tkinter.Canvas```.